# Set partitioning

Tags: optimization, prolog, partitioning, constraint-programming

I'm trying to get a good grasp with this problem but I'm struggling.
 Let's say that I have a S={1,2,3,4,5}, an L={(1,3,4),(2,3),(4,5),(1,3),(2),(5)} and an other tuple with the costs of L like C={10,20,12,15,4,10}

I want to make a constraint program in Prolog so as to take the solution that solves the problem with the minimum cost.(in this occasion it is the total sum of the costs of the subsets i will get)

My problem is that I cannot understand the way I'll make my modelisation. What I know is that I should choose a modelisation of binary variables {0,1} but I hardly understand how i will manage to express it via Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an explicit model for your problem instance makes things a bit clearer:

```
cover(SetsUsed, Cost) :-

    SetsUsed = [A,B,C,D,E,F],       % a Boolean for each set
    SetsUsed #:: 0..1,

    A         + D         #= 1,     % use one set with element 1
        B         + E     #= 1,     % use one set with element 2
    A + B     + D         #= 1,     % use one set with element 3
    A     + C             #= 1,     % use one set with element 4
            C         + F #= 1,     % use one set with element 5

    Cost #= 10*A + 20*B + 12*C + 15*D + 4*E + 10*F.
```

You can solve this e.g. in [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org):

```
?- cover(SetsUsed,Cost), branch_and_bound:minimize(labeling(SetsUsed), Cost).

SetsUsed = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Cost = 24
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Comment: For unknown lists I check for every number in which list is included so as to make the constraint set with that number?                                                 For example, if 3 is in the 1st,2nd and 4th list... I check the initial sets and wherever I find number 3 I store it so as to make the constraint A+B+D #=1 ??? Thank you very very much

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way to do it: You can use Boolean **indicators** to denote which elements comprise a subset. For example, in your case:

```
subsets(Sets) :-
    Sets = [[1,0,1,1,0]-10,  % {1,3,4}
            [0,1,1,0,0]-20,  % {2,3}
            [0,0,0,1,1]-12,  % {4,5}
            [1,0,1,0,0]-15,  % {1,3}
            [0,1,0,0,0]-4,   % {2}
            [0,0,0,0,1]-10]. % {5}
```

I now use SICStus Prolog and its [**Boolean constraint solver**](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dclpb.html#lib_002dclpb) to express set covers:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

setcover(Cover, Cost) :-
        subsets(Sets),
        keys_and_values(Sets, Rows, Costs0),
        transpose(Rows, Cols),
        same_length(Rows, Coeffs),
        maplist(cover(Coeffs), Cols),
        labeling(Coeffs),
        phrase(coeff_is_1(Coeffs, Rows), Cover),
        phrase(coeff_is_1(Coeffs, Costs0), Costs),
        sumlist(Costs, Cost).

cover(Coeffs, Col) :-
        phrase(coeff_is_1(Col,Coeffs), Cs),
        sat(card([1],Cs)).

coeff_is_1([], []) --> [].
coeff_is_1([1|Cs], [L|Ls]) --> [L], coeff_is_1(Cs, Ls).
coeff_is_1([0|Cs], [_|Ls]) --> coeff_is_1(Cs, Ls).
```

For each subset, a Boolean variable is used to denote whether that subset is part of the cover. Cardinality constraints make sure that each element is covered exactly once.

Example query and its result:

```
| ?- setcover(Cover, Cost).
Cover = [[0,0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]],
Cost = 31 ? ;
Cover = [[1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1]],
Cost = 24 ? ;
no
```

I leave picking a cover with minimum cost as an easy exercise.

Comment: Even though I don't get the part with SICStus and the Boolean constraint solver thanks for the answer,I hope I'll manage to make what I want